# JavaScript: Join() and Match() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to reverse a string, and filter out non-alpha characters. But for some reason the function returns an array instead of a string.

```
var palindromes = function(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase().split("").reverse("").join("");
    return str.match(/[a-z]/g);
}
```

If I pass **"foof!"** I expect **"foof"**, but instead I get **["f", "o", "o", "f"]** What's really odd is *return str* returns the string, but of course the punctuation remains. So it seems like **match()** is causing a problem.

Comment: why `match` there to check for palindrome? shouldn't it just be `return str.toLowerCase().split("").reverse("").join("") == str` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match says the return value of `match` is an array...

Comment: @putvande oooohhhh...so if it's an array, what method can I use instead?

Comment: `str.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');` to filter non-alpha characters

Comment: I also noticed **return str.match(/[a-z]/g).join("");** gives me the expected result...at least so far.

Comment: sure will. I would personally go with `replace` function if my intention is to prune something. `match` and then `join` is additional looping on results and can be bad for performance

Comment: @kiddorails I actually ended up going with replace and getting the function (the full and complete function, not just what I posted) working. Thanks for your help, and I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your intention**:  filter out non-alpha characters.
You should use `str.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');` for that. `[^a-z]` is a negative character group which will select all the characters except a-z, and `replace` will allow you to replace the value with `''`

Your function name is `palindrome`, for which the check doesn't make sense. The palindrome could easily be checked with:

```
return str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('') === str.toLowerCase()
```

You are using `match` in your original code which has different behaviour on basis of flags passed. It will give all the matching results in an array if global(`g`) flag is passed. It will give the result in array with the matching value on 0th position if `g` is not used.

```js
str = 'foof'
console.log(str.match(/[a-z]+/))
console.log(str.match(/[a-z]/g))
```

Comment: `.reverse()` takes no parameter, and shouldn't it be `=== str.toLowerCase()`? I would personally expect `Foof` to pass a palindrome test, though I'm not sure what the author's intention was for cases like that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you are right. I didn't check the expression carefully enough; edited to `str.toLowerCase().reverse() === str.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Strings have no `.reverse()` method, the `.split("")` and `.join("")` were necessary...